# Loop through this XML file until specific artist name is found PHP

Tags: php, xml, loops, filter

I need help. I have a large XML file with artist information that I need to scan through. What I need to do is loop through this file until the artist name is found. Then grab the child elements for only that specific artist.

For example, here is part of the xml file with a couple artists listed:

```
<artists page="1" perPage="100" totalPages="253081" total="25308020">
<artist>
<name>David Bowie</name>
<playcount>151727648</playcount>
<listeners>3969219</listeners>
<mbid>5441c29d-3602-4898-b1a1-b77fa23b8e50</mbid>
<url>http://www.last.fm/music/David+Bowie</url>
<streamable>0</streamable>
<image size="small">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/34s/937d62bb145040b9b709319c1e680037.png
</image>
<image size="medium">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/64s/937d62bb145040b9b709319c1e680037.png
</image>
<image size="large">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/174s/937d62bb145040b9b709319c1e680037.png
</image>
<image size="extralarge">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/937d62bb145040b9b709319c1e680037.png
</image>
<image size="mega">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/937d62bb145040b9b709319c1e680037.png
</image>
</artist>
<artist>
<name>The Beatles</name>
<playcount>456495139</playcount>
<listeners>3986977</listeners>
<mbid>b10bbbfc-cf9e-42e0-be17-e2c3e1d2600d</mbid>
<url>http://www.last.fm/music/The+Beatles</url>
<streamable>0</streamable>
<image size="small">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/34s/55efc33bcd234fd8a1d65b3d49bf9661.png
</image>
<image size="medium">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/64s/55efc33bcd234fd8a1d65b3d49bf9661.png
</image>
<image size="large">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/174s/55efc33bcd234fd8a1d65b3d49bf9661.png
</image>
<image size="extralarge">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/55efc33bcd234fd8a1d65b3d49bf9661.png
</image>
<image size="mega">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/55efc33bcd234fd8a1d65b3d49bf9661.png
</image>
</artist>
</artists>
```

Lets say I was searching this large file for information specific to "The Beatles". How would I loop through this file until it reaches The Beatles' section and then only grab the information specific to them (specifically the image size-large)?

I can, of course, simply loop through the entire file and grab elements that way, but for all artists:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($hot_artists_file);
$artist = $xml->artists->artist;

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $artist_name = $artist->name;
        $artist_url = $artist->url;
        $artist_pic_large = $artist->image[2];
        $artist_pic_mega = $artist->image[4];
        $artist_id = $artist->mbid;
        $artist_play_count = $artist->playcount;
        $artist_listeners = $artist->listeners;
    }
```

I have attempted to use xpath but I kept getting Invalid Expression errors. I then tried a while() loop which didn't work either. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

If you need more info, I'm happy to supply it. As always, thanks.

Comment: Though I have used DOMDocument. https://3v4l.org/8P4Na

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thanks for the link. Looks like a cool tool. Although, I'm not sure what to do with the output. Is there a way to now loop through that information and grab the artist info that I need?

Comment: The output looks like artist information to me. Read the php code. ;)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I think you misunderstood, I am trying to grab only ONE artists information out of that file at a time. I know how to loop through and grab all artists, but I need to be able to grab only one specific artist at a time  and ignore all other information in the xml. Is there a way to do that? :)

Comment: Check if the name is equal to the one you want, do what you want with it and then use `break;` to break the loop.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks let me try that. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath, you can use predicate (`[]`) to filter element with certain criteria, for example :

```
.....
$artist = $xml->xpath("/artists/artist[name='The Beatles']")[0]; 
echo $artist->name;
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/507055)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
The Beatles
```

The above XPath means *find `artist` element that is direct child of `artists` and has child element `name` value equals `"The Beatles"`*

Comment: That's awesome. Let me play with that a bit and I'll get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Got the name working, and that's a major leap in the right direction. Since you helped me get that working, everything else should be (fairly) simple. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know it already helped, because I missed to read that you specifically want to grab the image size large, until just now

Comment: So another hint, use `@` at the beginning of attribute name to reference attribute in XPath. This is another demo specifically to get image with size attribute equals `"large"` : https://eval.in/507070

Comment: No worries, I got the image size by: $artist->image[2]. :)

Comment: That is great. I truly appreciate your help on this issue. You just recharged my battery!